# how to convert macro enabled excel to normal one?

Tags: xml, excel, xslt, spreadsheet, vba

My requirement is to enter some values in spreadsheet which has some validations which are done using macros. After saving the document i have to give this as input to other application which accepts only a plain spreadsheet with out macros. so i have to convert the updated spread sheet to plain one with out macros. 
The solution which i find is we can do it using XSLT.I tried but not done. please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

In excel 2007 onwards you can save the sheet as an xlsx which will strip the macros. To see the effect of this though you will need to close the workbook and reopen it.

Comment: i have an excel sheet with some fields which have validaions, done using macros. so when user try to give invalid data it will prompt with error message after all the valid data is entered i want the macros should be disabled i mean the macros should be removed and a plain excel document should be required with the updated data.

Comment: I'm on the train so can't verify this works: but try selecting the entire worksheet, right click and choose clear -> validation.

Comment: it should not be done manually. when the user updated the sheet and uploaded the uploaded document should automatically converted to plain sheet with out macros with the updated data.